# How important is /usr/bin/google_accounts_daemon to a GCE VM's functioning?

Tags: memory, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

`htop` suggests that `google_accounts_daemon` is taking up 3 percent of my VM's RAM.

```
USER VIRT  RES   SHR CPU% MEM% Command
root 67480 16816 3292 0.0  2.8 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/google_accounts_daemon
```

I'm running into OOM conditions --usually when config management runs -- and I'm curious if I can disable this service without serious consequence.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite critical for all the virtual machines that are running in Google Cloud. This and the other processes are being used by the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) to retrieve or send information about the running machine. Also, it might aid when [live migration](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration) happens.